# Javafx - opening tab with another thread increase memory consumption

Tags: user-interface, javafx, tabs

I am creating a new Tab in JavaFX with another thread everything works as expected besides the fact that when I click the close button to close the tab the instance itself not being killed. I can see the memory increases with every tab that I open and does not decrease when I close the tab.

Here is the code to create the tab:

```
Task<Parent> loadTask = new Task<>() {
            @Override
            protected Parent call() throws Exception {
                FileXML xmlFile;
                FXMLLoader fxmlLoader;

                if (controller instanceof ProcedureController) {
                    fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxmls/procedureTab.fxml"));
                    xmlFile = (FileXML) ActionsFactory.getActionsFactory().createAction(Procedure.type);
                    ((Procedure) xmlFile).getExecutionProperties().setExecutionType(ExecutionType.NORMAL);
                    xmlFile.setFilePath(file.getAbsolutePath());
                    Platform.runLater(() -> setGraphic(initImageViewForButtonSize(PROCEDURE.IMAGE, 28)));
                } else {
                    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Controller Type is mismatch");
                }

                fxmlLoader.setController(controller);
                tabController = controller;

                setClosable(true);

                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    setText(file.getName());
                    getTabPane().setTabMinHeight(35);
                    getTabPane().setTabMaxHeight(35);
                });

                controller.getFileLoader().setFile(file);
                controller.getFileLoader().set(xmlFile);

                Parent parent = null;
                try {
                    parent = fxmlLoader.load();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    logger.error(getStackTraces(e));
                }

                FileLoaderToolBar.setEditorController(editorController);

                if (isNew) {
                    xmlFile.setAuthor(systemPreferences().getReporterPreferences().getName());
                    ((AutoTesterFile<?>) xmlFile).setName(FilenameUtils.removeExtension(file.getName()));
                    xmlFile.save();
                } else xmlFile.load();


                if (controller instanceof ProcedureController){
                    xmlFile.setFilePath(file.getAbsolutePath());
                }

                controller.getFileLoader().setAndUpdateUI(xmlFile);

                return parent;
            }
        };

        loadTask.setOnFailed(event -> {
            Throwable throwable = event.getSource().getException();
            if (throwable == null)
                new Alerts().raiseErrorAlert("Error", "Something went wrong :(", "Unknown issue occurred", false);
            else {
                Exception exception = new Exception(throwable);
                new Alerts().raiseExceptionAlert(exception, exception.getMessage(), false);
            }
        });

        loadTask.setOnSucceeded(event -> {
            setContent(loadTask.getValue());
            if (editorController == null) return;
            if (!editorController.getEditorTabPane().isLastTabInPlace())
                editorController.getEditorTabPane().getTabs().add(new AutoTesterTab(editorController));
        });

        Thread thread = new Thread(loadTask);
        thread.setName("AutoTesterTabLoaderThread");
        thread.start();
```

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: .. that said: you might want to check the bug database, I seem to faintly remember that tabPane/Skin has a memory leak somewhere

Comment: How are you profiling this? Do you actually see out of memory errors?

Comment: I am using VisualVM and also looking at the memory in the task manager. Each time I open a tab and close it I see memory increase without decreasing. Also, it might not be only the tabs that causing issues. It might be possible that I have other objects that are not being cleaned properly, could be due to references issues, I am still investigating this but unable to find the root cause

Comment: Why would you expect the memory to decrease when you close a tab? The memory would only decrease if the garbage collector detected that it needed to run.

Comment: You are correct, as I mentioned in my previous comment this could be an issue of objects still being referenced and the GC is not cleaning them. I am still investigating the issue, also I so bugs related to TabPane and tabs but not sure it is related

Comment: *”this could be an issue of objects still being referenced and the GC is not cleaning them”*. You miss my point. It could be that the GC has not run yet, even if there is no reference to the objects. There is no guarantee as to when heap space will be reclaimed.

Comment: So how I can check that? I try to run System.gc() after closing the tab but also they say in doc that this not guarantees that GC will execute. So I am not sure how I can debug this

Comment: One quick and dirty way is to set the maximum heap space to, for example, halfway between the amount of memory used when you start the application and the amount of memory you see being used when you’ve opened a few tabs. Then run it and see if it runs out of memory, or if the garbage collector reclaims the memory. The more advanced way is to dig into VisualVM and see what objects are accessible after closing a tab. (I don’t know the details of doing that off the top of my head.)

Comment: Yeah I tried to use VisualVM but it is a very daunting task because there is lots of data that hard to filter. I used the memory section in intellij while debugging and saw that my tabs only goes up as well as objects related to the tabs.